# fabric-ca-client enroll with error: post http:/localhost:7054/enroll x509: certificate is valid for someip not localhost

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, admin, ca

I have a question which is about the hyperledger minifabric ca enrollment. I have set up a network with 3 organizations and 3 ca's one for each. After I created my channel, joined and run the discover command.

Then, I have entered the docker container in order to created some users.

First I exported the ca client home.

`export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=cacerts`

`fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://Admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles /certs/ca/cert.pem`

And then I run the above command in order to enroll the admin user which is already created in the minifabric network. But I face always the following error:

[image]

I can't imagine what is going wrong since I have followed the same steps several times before and all have worked as expected with no errors.

Also in the logs of the ca container I get the following line:

```
2021/09/28 08:56:01 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:38274: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due changed IP address. When I have started for first time the minifabric, it registered with the current IP of the pc. After I have restarted the pc, the IP has changed and the minifabric was up with another IP.

So, in case you are using minifabric locally, you have to set your static IPin the spec.yaml file as `localhost`, or use a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate which you are providing in --tls.certfiles is wrong. You need to provide proper path for **tls-cert.pem**